# remove the class due to which the on click event started after ajax call

Tags: jquery

i am trying to remove that class on which i click and the the on click event fires and the ajax call is made. but its not working . I wanted to know if its possible or not

```
$(document).on('click', '.miinterest', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var login_id = $(this).attr('lid');
    var profile_id = $(this).attr('pid');
    var type = 'interest';
    var dataString = "login_id=" + login_id + "&profile_id=" + profile_id + "&type=" + type;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (html) {
            $(".miinterest").addClass("disabled");
            $(this).removeClass("miinterest");
            $.lightbox("modules/after_message/after_message.php?page=profile&type=" + type, {
                'width': 480,
                    'height': 240,
                    'autoresize': true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Test what context your `$(this)` is in, and see if it returns what you clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to your element under `var type='interest';`

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Later on `success` call

```
$this.removeClass("miinterest");
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the context setting of jQuery.

```
context: $(this)
```

Your usage of `$(this)` inside your success callback is referring to the jqXHR object and not your original scope.